# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word как установить

Tags: c#, wpf

Установлена 13 студия максимальная, хочу добавить в проект ссылку на пакет Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, но его там нету.

Весь пакет офиса 2007 установлен на компе.

Вопрос
Где искать этот пакет и как потом его добавлять, чтобы он отображался в ссылках добавляемых пакетов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правый клик на `References` --> `Add Reference`, затем перейти на вкладку `COM`, в поле поиска для `Excel` вбить `Microsoft Excel`.